# XML PATH value in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, for-xml-path

i am using XML PATH to bind a multi valued column, the query is working fine but the result is in xml form and i want to convert it into simple text
 Here is the Query

```
 SELECT soo.order_id,
 sum(oo.total)AS total,
 items=(SELECT si.item_name FROM sub_order i,Items si
 WHERE i.order_id=soo.order_id and si.item_id=i.item_id  FOR XML PATH(''))
 FROM Orders oo
 INNER JOIN Sub_Order soo ON oo.order_id = soo.order_id
 INNER JOIN Items
 ON soo.item_id = Items.item_id 
 group by soo.order_id
```

and result of "items" field is like

```
 <item_name>cake</item_name><item_name>soap</item_name>
```

but i want it to be like     `cake,soap`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
items=(SELECT si.item_name FROM sub_order i,Items si
 WHERE i.order_id=soo.order_id and si.item_id=i.item_id  FOR XML PATH(''))
```

with

```
items=STUFF((SELECT ',' + si.item_name FROM sub_order i,Items si
 WHERE i.order_id=soo.order_id and si.item_id=i.item_id  FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
```